# Vue 3 watch function not updating

Tags: vuejs3, reactive-programming, watch, computed-properties

i'm trying to update a variable on the status of a HTMLInputElement, but the watch method doesn't react on a change from the input field.

```
const input = ref<HTMLInputElement | null>(null)
const filename = ref("Foo")

watch(() => input.value?.files, (first) => {
    console.log(input.value?.files?.item(0)?.name, filename.value, first)
})
```

```
<div>
   {{ filename }}
</div>
<input type="file" class="hidden" ref="input"/>
```

I tried to use a computed property and to use `watchEffect()` but both didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how reactivity works in Vue. The ref to a DOM element does not trigger a watch. I suggest to use a change handler:

```
<script setup>
const fileName = ref("Foo");

const handleFileChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
        fileName.value = e.target.files[0].name;
        console.log(fileName.value);
    }
}
</script>
<template>
    <div>
       {{ filename }}
    </div>
    <input type="file" class="hidden" @change="handleFileChange($event)"/>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you just need to bind the reactive property to the input using `v-model`.

But I have just learned that `v-model` does work on file inputs.

> [Vue warn]: Template compilation error: v-model cannot be used on file
> inputs since they are read-only. Use a v-on:change listener instead.

So we have to use `v-on:change` event. For one file it's pretty simple:

```
<input type="file" @change="fileName = $event.target.value" />
```

For a `multiple` file input we have to get the file names from the array of File objects.

### Here is the working Playground

```js
const { createApp, ref  } = Vue;

const App = {
  setup() {
    const fileName = ref('test');
    const fileNames = ref([]);    
    const onChanged = (event) => {
        const files = [];        
        for(var i = 0; i < event.target.files.length; i++) {
            files.push(event.target.files[i].name);
        }
        fileNames.value = files;        
    }
    return { fileName, fileNames, onChanged }  
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
   fileName: {{ fileName }}<br />
  <input type="file" @change="fileName = $event.target.value" /><br />
   fileNames: {{ fileNames }}<br />
  <input type="file" @change="onChanged" multiple /><br />
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```